# Twilio Send location in whatsup

Tags: java, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-programmable-chat

Using Twilio, I'm trying to send a WhatsUp location. [twilio doc](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/whatsapp/api?code-sample=code-send-a-whatsapp-location-message&code-language=Java&code-sdk-version=7.x)

Maven dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.twilio.sdk</groupId>
        <artifactId>twilio</artifactId>
        <version>7.42.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Sample code

```
Twilio.init(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN);
    Message message = Message.creator(
            new com.twilio.type.PhoneNumber("whatsapp:+15005550006"),
            new com.twilio.type.PhoneNumber("whatsapp:+14155238886"),
            "Twilio HQ")
        .setPersistentAction(
            Arrays.asList("geo:37.787890,-122.391664|375 Beale St"))
        .create();
```

I'm getting below error

> The method setPersistentAction(Arrays.asList(geo)) is undefined for the type MessageCreator

Answer (score 0):

Have you upgraded your Twilio Java Helper library SDK? Usually newer functionality requires an upgrade. It looks like 7.45.1 added it: [Read Status and Location Message Available on the Twilio API for Whatsapp](https://www.twilio.com/changelog/read-status-and-location-message-available-twilio-api-whatsapp)

[Release Notes](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-java/releases)